# Error code -7 when trying to install release APK

Tags: java, android

I've taken all appropriate steps to create the release APK. ([Demonstration of steps required](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio))

My device (Nexus 7 2012) is set to allow installs from unknown sources.

I emailed the APK (app-release.apk) to myself and attempted to open it from GMail, as this should work.

EDIT: I apologize, I also should have included that I did uninstall the app from settings > apps > (app in question) > "uninstall" button.

However, the app immediately fails to load, with only the following logcat info:

```
05-30 14:44:41.689      466-497/? W/PackageManager﹕ Package edu.osu.expandablelistviewtest1 signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
05-30 14:44:41.914      466-497/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 74971(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 22(1348KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 28MB/43MB, paused 9.752ms total 220.463ms
05-30 14:44:41.927  20704-20704/? D/InstallAppProgress﹕ Installation error code: -7
05-30 14:44:43.094  20704-20704/? I/InstallAppProgress﹕ Finished installing edu.osu.expandablelistviewtest1
```

I've tried every search string I can think of and can't find any information on error -7's meaning. Looking at the [code on GitHub](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/47fe118e0178e9d72c98073ff588ee5cf353258e/src/com/android/packageinstaller/InstallAppProgress.java), we see the following code:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
  ...
  if (msg.arg1 == PackageManager.INSTALL_SUCCEEDED) {
    ...
  } else if (msg.arg1 == PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE){
    ...
   } else {
    // Generic error handling for all other error codes.
    centerTextDrawable.setLevel(1);
    centerExplanationLabel = getExplanationFromErrorCode(msg.arg1);
    centerTextLabel = R.string.install_failed;
    mLaunchButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
  ...
  private int getExplanationFromErrorCode(int errCode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installation error code: " + errCode);
    switch (errCode) {
    case PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK:
      return R.string.install_failed_invalid_apk;
    case PackageManager.INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES:
      return R.string.install_failed_inconsistent_certificates;
    case PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK:
      return R.string.install_failed_older_sdk;
    case PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE:
      return R.string.install_failed_cpu_abi_incompatible;
    default:
      return -1;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

...so we have no way of knowing what the "-7" means. (Beyond that it is none of the switch cases.)

I'm open to any ideas / suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Do have that app previously installed on your device ?

Comment: I uninstalled it from settings > apps > (the app in question) > "uninstall" button

Comment: Even after uninstalling your app, now when you try to install, it gives the same error ?

Comment: Yes. I made sure to uninstall the app before attempting to install from download.

Comment: I am assuming `edu.osu.expandablelistviewtest1` is the package name of your app. Not sure but try restarting phone or sign it with the same key that you did before. Its complaining that you sign it with a different key.. but ideally uninstalling should have worked..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, I feel sheepish. After all that, the issue was that in newer versions of Android, uninstalling in the manner I mentioned above only uninstalls for that specific user.

The answer is to go to settings > apps > (app in question) and then to select "uninstall for all users" from the "..." menu in the upper right.

So for future Google searchers:

InstallAppProgress﹕ Installation error code: -7 evidently means you have to completely uninstall a previous version of your app, such as previous debug versions, etc.

Comment: In addition to this correct answer: I was in the deadlock, that the signed APK could not be installed (error code -7), but the debug version was already uninstalled. So, first the debug version has to be installed again, this should word. After that, remove by "uninstall for all users". After that, the signed release APK can be installed.

Comment: I can't figure out how I half uninstalled my app only for my user (who is supposed to be the only one). This answer saved me a lot of time. Thank you man.

Comment: Thanks man, I found a solution..
Another solution is to run 'adb uninstall com.ephesoft.snapdoc'..

Answer (score 4):

The error code constants for **PackageInstaller** are defined in [PackageManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/78db19c25a3a18d9ccf19b91be17e791e4fd782c/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#397) class with prefixes like **INSTALL_FAILED_**.

(the link corresponds to a code revision from Jun 25 2015, so by the time you read this, the code might change.)